# multiple view of multiple controller in single page Yii PHP

Tags: php, architecture, yii

I have a problem in architect.I had two page order and registration and they were working using these views and controller separately.

> 1.registration(view),RegistrationForm(Form Model) and RegistrationConroller(Controller).
>
> 2.order(view),OrderForm(Form Model) and OrderController(Controller).

Now the problem is i have new requirement that is to display both order and registration view in a single page.when user submit it will register the user and place the order after validation.

The problem in this requirement is which controller is going to process there request because each view ( registration and order) had separate controller.
Now should i make a new controller  then It will require code repetition.
Please suggest me the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Yii has an option by which you can import/serve actions defined in other controllers.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#actions-detail

The link above details the process of defining external actions in your controller.

So in essence, you can refer to actions defined in Order Controller without replicating the code.

Comment: so you mean I create another controler Class e.g. OrderRegistrationController extends CCController and overide actions method and define the mapping of required actions of both controller here ?

Comment: If  above is correct then tell me when user click on mergeviewpage submit button what will be the action where the user is submitting both forms ? eg. localhost/index.php?r=orderregistration/whataction ??

Comment: No, the two controllers you have created are fine, from what I understand, you wish to provide 'Order' and 'Registration' functionality in one page. If my understanding is correct, you just need to override the actions() method in your Order Controller to make it import the 'actionRegister()' (I presume) into your Order Controller, then you can post to that action as you would initially in the Registration Controller action.

Comment: Ok I understand,I ll import 'actionRegister' of RegisterController into OrderController 'action' Method but now the problem is which action is going to render the combineview.php page e.g. which action will contain this statement :

$this->render('combineview'array("orderform"=>$orderform,
"registerform"=>$registerForm));

Comment: Ah, for that you'll need to move all the common code to separate functions or, you can have both the form models posted to the same controller and then validate them both and save accordingly.